# video file download issue

Tags: video, download, flash, windows-media-player, http

On some web sites, I can use either the web page embedded Flash player or use the web page embedded Windows Media Player to play the remote video. However there is no download link. Are there any tools or utilities to download the video to my local PC? I heard there are some magic tools for this purpose, but I have no idea what they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general tool for downloading any embedded video.

For Firefox there is multiple [plugins](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fast-video-download-with-searc/) to achieve this on specific sites. [Download Embedded](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/download-embedded/) works for embedded objects like WMV (Windows Media Video) files, but not for flash movies.

Comment: Or if you're feeling brave, you could play around in the cache folder, but the Flash guys are getting sneaky with that nowadays.

Comment: Where is the cache folder?